# Which word I can use as unit to count for fish/shimp and animal?

Tags: measuring-units

[Sorry for bad English]

In a list I have:

```
Item       Unit     Amount
Choptick   Pair     1
Fan        Pieces   1
Lobster    ???      1
Tuna       ???      1
Chicken    ???      1
Pig        ???      1
```

(choptick and fan are for example)

In the `???` place, I need words which mean a single and whole (alive) lobster/tuna/chicken/pig. Which words should I use?

I use this list in a restaurant, where the guest see and choose a fish/chicken, then choose how to cook. Then they will pay as how much that fish/chicken weight.

**Edit:**

As the comment bellow, I make my question more clear: All that fish/animal are alive when the guest order (include the pig, we have a pig breeds which the biggest, full growth one is less than 10 kg, use for party, and we have a farm near restaurant for guest see and pick a pig). And all the `???` place not neccessery use the same word. I need the best word possible for each position. Thank!

Comment: I would just write "whole", the meaning is quite clear then. Can I come to your restaurant and eat a whole pig?

Comment: I would say "Whole".

Comment: "Each" is commonly used in this scenario.

Comment: Actually @ste I think "each" is better than "whole", as "whole" implies that it hasn't been cooked/prepared - eg that you're going to get a chicken with it's head, claws, feathers, guts etc still attached, whereas you're going (I assume) to get a prepared and cooked chicken.

Comment: I'll point out that the above-described restaurant would not last very long in the US before it was being picketed 24/7 by PETA, ASPCA, and others.  So responses from US residents are probably not relevant.

Comment: Your country seems to use kg instead of pound and what is wrong with using kg for the unit? I really don't understand your question? What is your question?

Comment: @HotLicks, I think you are exaggerating. There might be some localities where this would be a minor problem, but for the vast rural areas of the Central US, nobody would bat an eye, and artisanal and whole animal butchering is a huge trend right now. It seems to be following the trajectory of the microbrewing trend.

Comment: @PhilSweet - In the "vast rural areas of the Central US" no one would attempt to open a restaurant of this sort.  They'd be laughed out of town.

Comment: @Rathony because the fish/animal alive, you choose the small one if you come alone, or big one if you come with lot of people (or serveral small one). Sometime, if we are out of small fish (for example under 1 kg), if you order 0.5kg fish and we have a 3kg fish, if I accept the order then I cannot sell the remain 2.5 kg. For some reason we only accept the order in a whole fish.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes my restaurant is locate in Halong, Vietnam a famous destination for tourist. We have a lot of Vietnamese, Chinese and Korean tourist (beside Japanese, American and European), who often come as a group 4 - 10 people and they like the way our restaurant serve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider ***["each"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/each)*** [Oxford Dictionary]

> Used to refer to every one of two or more people or things, regarded and identified separately

I have seen many a menu use "each" to denote quantity in the manner you describe.

Comment: The problem is that "each" is rather ambiguous.

Comment: I do agree with that, but I have often seen in supermarkets etc.: pasta, 1kg; water, 2l; apples, ea.

Comment: @Ste I edited my questtion to add some info. And do the guest misundertood `each` as each disk/kg/... or they have to ask me "each what"? (I don't know because I'm not native English speaker)

Comment: @Sakura If you see "Pig: $20 each", you know that it is $20 per pig.  You wouldn't be asked "each what?" as it is clear that it is $20 for each pig.  You may receive questions about which part of the pig you mean but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @Ste I got it! thank alot for your answer and comments